# Google play developer console crash reports

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-developer-api

I am looking for an API to pull my app's crash reports programmatically and I can't seem to find if this exists or not. I read through the google play developer API docs but it seems like it's for publishing your app and managing game related actions.

Anyone know if there is an API available for crash reports?

Edit: I can't modify the app, as it's supplied by a vendor but published through our Google Play Developer account. I only have access to the play developer console's ANRS & Crash Reports.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

EDIT, quote from the support site:

> As of May 2018, you can no longer download detailed reports for crashes and ANRs.

Old answer:

You can access Crashes and ANR's using gsutil

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6135870?hl=en

e.g. 
Command

gs://[developer_bucket_id]/crashes/anrs_[package_name]_YYYYMM.csv

gsutil tool link - 
https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil

Comment: This looks like exactly what I need! Thank you!

Comment: so as of May 2018, how do you go about downloading detailed reports/clusters?

Comment: i am getting 'no such file or directory' found when using the above gsutil command with my developer bucket id. anything to be taken care of while installation?

Comment: @nooby - Not sure why that will happen. Open question on stackoverflow so someone will guide you.

Answer (score 4):

You can use Firebase crash report. All you got to do is add the dependency in gradle.

[Official Document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crash/android)

Comment: I can't actually modify the app, it's a vendor supplied app published by us, so I only have access to the play console. 
This would definitely work though if I could do it :(

Comment: Even if you had access to Firebase crash reporting, how do you actually go and download the reports programmatically? (or even manually)?